# Starting a WebView in a TabActivity

Tags: java, android, webview

I'm looking to have a WebView popup in my Android application (for OAuth permissions stuff), but I'm running into some problems. Following the Android online guide, I would do the following:

```
WebView webView = new WebView(this);
setContentView(webView);
webView.loadUrl(URL_HERE);
```

My problem is that the Activity this is in, is actually a TabActivity. When I try to start my application, I get a `java.lang.RuntimeException` saying that my "content must have a TabHost whos id arrtibute is ...".  How would I be able to start the WebView at the start of my application without running into this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to create separate activities to place inside the tabs. Then, you can add your WebView to one of them. your TabActivity must contain `<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`.

> The TabHost requires that a TabWidget and a FrameLayout both live somewhere within it. To position the TabWidget and FrameLayout vertically, a LinearLayout is used. The FrameLayout is where the content for each tab goes, which is empty now because the TabHost will automatically embed each Activity within it.

Notice that the TabWidget and the FrameLayout elements have the IDs tabs and tabcontent, respectively. These names must be used so that the TabHost can retrieve references to each of them. It expects exactly these names.

You can follow the [Tab Layout tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html) for an example.

If, on the other hand, you want a popup instead of a tab, check [Creating a Custom Dialog](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomDialog)

Comment: I have a tabbed layout going on already. I just need the WebView to come up for the user to give the application permission to access their data. Should I instead create an Activity JUST for the WebView, then call an Intent to that Activity when I need to use it, from the TabActivity?

Comment: In that case, I would use a dialog (see the last link I posted). Alternatively, you could add a webview in your first tab and set its visibility to GONE once logged in (tho I think the dialog is a better option)

Comment: A WebView inside a dialog? I've never heard of / seen that before, I don't think.

Comment: why not? Anyhow, if you don't like that option, use the other one. Or create an activity just for the sake of authorization and then remove the tab from the tabhost. Your call. Plenty of options to choose from. All will work, except `this.setContentView(webView);` inside a TabActivity.